# Regular expression invalid when replacing in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

```
$100 = "$env:APPDATA/somthing"
$iamhere = "C:/example"
$100 = $100 -replace "`$env:APPDATA\somthing", "$iamhere"
```

I want `$100` replaced by `$iamhere` of its contents (in text form) although I get this error.

```
Regular expression pattern is not valid: $env:APPDATA\somthing.
At line:1 char:1
$100 = $100 -replace "`$env:APPDATA\somthing", "$iamhere"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ($env:APPDATA\somthing:String) [], RuntimeException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

I think this is because I am trying to replace some text with a directory, but I want the text inside the variable of `$iamhere`

Comment: Based on what you're asking, why not just set $100 to $iamhere e.g. `$100 = $iamhere`?  Also why are you escaping the `$` in the first parameter to the `-replace` operator?  Don't you want to match by the *contents* of the variable `$env:APPDATA\something`?

Answer (score 18):

The `-replace` operator will parse the input string you provide as a regular expression. The `\` character is a special character in regular expressions and so if you want it to be treated literally, you need to escape it by adding a `\` in front of it. Fortunately .NET provides a handy function for doing that for you:

```
# ~> [Regex]::Escape("$env:APPDATA/somthing")
C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming/somthing
```

So just update your example like this:

```
$100 = $100 -replace [Regex]::Escape("$env:APPDATA/somthing"), $iamhere
```

Note that you don't need the quotes around $iamhere (but since it's a string, it doesn't make a difference).

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. I typed in `[Regex]::Escape('$env:APPDATA\somthing')` (The single quotes escaping PowerShell to read the contents) This came up with `\$env:APPDATA\\something` and NOT `$env:APPDATA\\something` Any help to fix that @zdan ? Thanks, CollinScripter

Comment: @Collinscripter The output you are getting is correct. $ is also a special character in regex and MUST be escaped in order to replace it. If your original string really conatins '$env:APPDATA\somthing', then that's what you would need.

Answer (score 7):

you could use `*.replace` instead

```
$100 = "$env:APPDATA/somthing"

$iamhere = "C:/example"

$100 = $100.replace("$env:APPDATA/somthing", "$iamhere")
```

it won't use regex then

Comment: This is case-sensitive though, and might trip someone off.